# Retriving regular expression from database is different in java and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, regex, client, server

I've got a record in my database: `\w{3}_\d{5}`

When I retrieve that record to java string it comes as is: `\w{3}_\d{5}`

However when I am assigning that java string to JavaScript variable it looks as follows: `w{3}_d{5}` *i.e without back slashes*

So if I save it to the database as `\\w{3}_\\d{5}`

- Java String will be: `\\w{3}_\\d{5}`
- Java String assigned to JavaScript variable will be: `\w{3}_\d{5}`

To summarize the above - I need a regular expression to function on both (client and server), the only solution I see is to save a regular expression as `\\w{3}_\\d{5}` and get read of extra back slashes on java side.

Why does JavaScript looses the back slashes? Whats the best way to go around this?

Comment: How is the assignment to a JavaScript variable performed? You probably need to insert a character escape function in there, so that `"\"` will be escaped to `"\\"` before it reaches JavaScript.

Comment: @ Roger Gustavsson Please suggest whats the best way to do it? Is there simple way or need to parse a string and replace manually?

Comment: I've added the information as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a class with string escape functions suitable for different languages. The class is called [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) and has the static method `String = escapeJava(String)`.

---

An older version of the library had an `escapeJavaScript` method, but hopefully `escapeJava` will work just as well.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, just one correction to your answer. In StringEscapeUtils there is no such method as escapeJavaScript(String), there is escapeJava(String)

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be

```
\w{3}_\d{5}  ===> [a-zA-Z0-9_]{3}_[0-9]{5}
```

Comment: Thanks, but to complex, data captures are doing those, so the regular expressions are very simple.